# Hibernate: illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, tomcat

I have 2 methods:

```
public static Ticket issueTicket(User user,Service service,String[] seats) {
    Session ticSess= DB.factory.openSession();
    ticSess.beginTransaction();
    Date d= new Date();
    Ticket ticket=new Ticket(d, service, user);

    ticSess.save(ticket);
    ticSess.getTransaction().commit();
    int seatCount=seats.length;
    for (int i=0;i<seatCount;i++){
        int seatID=Integer.parseInt(seats[i]);
        Seat seat=getSeatByID(seatID);
        seat.setTicket(ticket);
        ticSess.update(seat);
    }
    return ticket;


}
```

and,

```
public static Seat getSeatByID(int seatID) {
    Session proSess = DB.factory.openSession();
    proSess.beginTransaction();
    Seat c = (Seat) (proSess.load(Seat.class, seatID));
    proSess.getTransaction().commit();

    return c;
}
```

when I call issueTicket method I get:

```
illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions
```

and If I close the session in getSeatByID method there will be another error telling that the session is closed. Here is the Stack Trace:

```
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:164)
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:285)
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
at ir.ac.shirazu.cse.Terminal.Seat_$$_javassist_9.setTicket(Seat_$$_javassist_9.java)
at ir.ac.shirazu.cse.Database.DB.issueTicket(DB.java:231)
```

Comment: After you added the stacktrace it seems that there is some lazy initialization taking place after leaving `getSeatByID()`. Just do everything in one session and it will work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try closing `proSess` in `getSeatByID()` before returning. Currently the `Seat` indeed remains attached to session opened in  `getSeatByID()`.

Comment: If I close the session in getSeatByID method there will be another error telling that the session is closed.

Comment: @Pishist 
Can you send full stacktrace of "closed session" exception? Maybe some lazy-initialization takes place at some point? Another thing is that I don't fully understand why you load the Seat in a separate session and transaction. You seem to open "transaction per DB operation" which is basically an anti-pattern.

Comment: I think if I load the Seat in the same session the problem will be solved.Thanks.
What should I do instead of transaction per DB operation?
I heard that the transactions won't effect the database until we close them...

Comment: @Pishist Read about unit of work here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem . But after using singleton pattern for session i'm done. I'm using Hibernate 4.2.x.

This is my session class is used to get sessions for DB transactions etc.

```
public class SessionClass {

static Session session = PoolManager.getSession();

public static Session getSession() {
    if (session != null || session.isOpen()) {
        return session;
    } else {
        session = PoolManager.getSession();
        return session;
    }
}
```

}

Hibernate Helper Class I'm using.

```
public class PoolManager {
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static final ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

static {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
        // config file.
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();

        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Log the exception. 
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static Session getSession() {
    return sessionFactory.openSession();
}
```

}

Comment: How do you deal with concurrency then?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when trying to associate a entity from a Envers Session.

Fixed that by "refreshing" said entity (retrieving it on my non-Envers session via PK fetch) before bubbling it up to my algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

use `session.opensession().get(.....)`.. instead of `session.opensession().load(.....)`

Answer (score -1):

what if you do a proSess.evict(c) before committing proSess?