# How to use @Transaction and Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, transactional

I need to implements Threads for running some processes in my Java App with Spring and I'm using @Transactional to manage the Hibernate Transaction and commit the changes to the DB.

The issue is that when I use @Transactional in the threads, I get `illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions`

I'm using @Transactional in the main thread (where I'm saving the objects in the database) and then call `Future` to execute the `threads` where I use @Transactional to recover and update the objects saved in the main thread, but I get the error mentioned above.

How is this suppose to work?

I tried to different flows and sending the IDs instead of the object to the threads, but in that way I get null from the database.

Comment: See in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407301/how-to-use-spring-transaction-in-multithread. Duplicated!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate: illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504591/hibernate-illegally-attempted-to-associate-a-proxy-with-two-open-sessions)

Comment: Well @AristofanioGarcia in that link they are using executors while I’m using Async methods. And there I’m not seeing that they have my problem. My problem is that although I have different threads, I want that the object in the main thread were visible for the child thread

Comment: @RomanKonoval there they are manually opening and closing the hibernate session while I’m using Transactional and I don’t have too much control over that

Comment: I don't see nothing about async in your question, but now is ok! Independ this you have the same problem. To help you, post an example, please!